# counting the duplicates in the arraylist

Tags: java, file, text, arraylist

I have a text file that contains:

```
File1.txt
File2.doc
File3.out
File4.txt
File5.so
File6.dll
```

I'm trying to get the output to return just the extension name and how many times it has occurred in the text file.

So for this specific file the output should return:
txt 2
doc 1
out 1
so 1
dll 1

The output needs to be in the java output, not the file it self.

I have this so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class prob03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("prob03.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> extensionsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split("\\.");
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String extension = parts[1];
            extensionsArray.add(extension);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < extensionsArray.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (extensionsArray.get(i).equals(extensionsArray.get(j))) {
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Please help me figure out this problem, I'm not trying to copy and this is not my homework or any kind of assignment. Let me know if I'm going in the right direction please. thank you

Comment: "Please help me figure out this problem" _what_ problem? Have you encountered any errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be really lazy, you can do something like:

```
int dupeCount = extensionsArray.size() - new HashSet<String>(extensionsArray).size();
```

Which basically subtracts the total number of elements by the number of unique elements (`Set`s don't allow duplicates), which will give you the number of elements that were a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap, where the key is the file extension and the value is the count of times you found it.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> extensionsCount = new HashMap<>();
for (String extension: extensionsArray) {
    Integer count = extensionsCount.get(extension);
    if (count == null) {
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;
    extensionsCount.put(extension, count);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashMap

```
ArrayList<String> files // <-- your list of filenames
HashMap<String, Integer> extensions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String filename : files) {
  String ext = filename.split(".")[1];
  if (extensions.containsKey()) {
    Integer count = extensions.get(ext);
    count++;
    extensions.put(ext, count);
  }
  else {
    extensions.put(ext, new Integer(1))
  }
}

for (String ext : extensions.ketSet()) {
   System.out.println(ext + ", " + exttensions.get(ext));
}
```

This will give you the counts of ALL file extensions.